# Value at Risk for a Portfolio Backtest

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to calculate measures for my portfolio backtest. I am using R package `PerformanceAnalytics`, and I want to apply/use its function `VaR` for every year where I've actually rebalanced my portfolio. This seems not to work, though I am pretty sure there must be a simple solution for it, as I have my table with all the logreturns needed, and a table with all the portfolio weights/year.

What I need is the VaR/year after the `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing` step.

```
port_ret <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
port_ret <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_ret, type="full_investment")
port_ret <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_ret, type="long_only")
port_ret <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_ret, type="box", min=0.0, max=0.2)
port_ret <- add.objective(portfolio=port_ret, type="quadratic_utility", risk_aversion=(4.044918))
port_ret <- add.objective(portfolio=port_ret, type="risk", name="StdDev")
port_ret <- add.objective(portfolio=port_ret, type="return", name="mean")

opt_rent<- optimize.portfolio(R=R, portfolio=port_ret, optimize_method="ROI", trace=TRUE)

plot(opt_rent, risk.col="StdDev", return.col="mean", main="Quadratic Utility Optimization", chart.assets=TRUE, xlim=c(0, 0.03), ylim=c(0, 0.002085))

extractStats(opt_rent) 
bt_port_rent <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R=R, portfolio= port_ret, optimize_method="ROI", rebalance_on="years", trace=TRUE, training_period= NULL)
chart.Weights(bt_port_rent,  ylim=c(0, 1))
extractStats(bt_port_rent)
weights_rent <- round(extractWeights(bt_port_rent),3)
VaR(R, weights= weights_rent, portfolio_method="component",method="historical")
```

The current VaR calculaction gives me an error (R are the daily returns of the indices used, and weights_rent are the weights for the rebalancing, see below). Important to add is that the weights_rent are yearly, wheareas R is a daily data:

```
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

I assume this is because the VaR calculation requires a vector of weights and not a table with 20 rows providing different weights, see the weights table below:

```
> weights_rent
             SPX   RUA  FTSE   DAX NKY MSCI EM  GOLD ASIA50   SSE  BBAG   REX  GSCI
1998-12-31 0.200 0.200 0.198 0.002   0   0.000 0.000  0.000 0.000 0.200 0.200 0.000
1999-12-31 0.200 0.159 0.000 0.188   0   0.000 0.000  0.200 0.076 0.177 0.000 0.000
2000-12-29 0.179 0.000 0.000 0.150   0   0.000 0.000  0.071 0.200 0.200 0.000 0.200
2001-12-31 0.147 0.000 0.000 0.045   0   0.000 0.077  0.122 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.010
2002-12-31 0.013 0.000 0.000 0.000   0   0.000 0.200  0.106 0.109 0.200 0.200 0.172
2003-12-31 0.000 0.053 0.000 0.000   0   0.000 0.200  0.137 0.071 0.200 0.200 0.140
2004-12-31 0.000 0.080 0.000 0.000   0   0.000 0.200  0.161 0.000 0.200 0.200 0.160
2005-12-30 0.000 0.070 0.000 0.000   0   0.000 0.200  0.193 0.000 0.200 0.145 0.191
2006-12-29 0.000 0.097 0.000 0.000   0   0.015 0.200  0.196 0.193 0.200 0.000 0.098
2007-12-31 0.000 0.008 0.000 0.017   0   0.130 0.200  0.125 0.200 0.200 0.000 0.120
2008-12-31 0.000 0.055 0.000 0.025   0   0.000 0.200  0.129 0.130 0.200 0.200 0.061
2009-12-31 0.000 0.051 0.000 0.010   0   0.007 0.200  0.145 0.162 0.200 0.200 0.024
2010-12-31 0.000 0.064 0.000 0.015   0   0.012 0.200  0.158 0.129 0.200 0.200 0.023
2011-12-30 0.000 0.098 0.000 0.000   0   0.000 0.200  0.149 0.119 0.200 0.200 0.035
2012-12-31 0.000 0.099 0.000 0.014   0   0.000 0.200  0.161 0.109 0.200 0.200 0.018
2013-12-31 0.000 0.134 0.000 0.025   0   0.000 0.200  0.146 0.095 0.200 0.200 0.000
2014-12-31 0.000 0.138 0.000 0.016   0   0.000 0.200  0.117 0.130 0.200 0.200 0.000
2015-12-31 0.000 0.129 0.000 0.041   0   0.000 0.200  0.102 0.127 0.200 0.200 0.000
2016-12-30 0.000 0.148 0.000 0.036   0   0.000 0.200  0.119 0.098 0.200 0.200 0.000
2017-12-29 0.000 0.151 0.000 0.018   0   0.000 0.200  0.146 0.085 0.200 0.200 0.000
2018-12-31 0.000 0.179 0.000 0.004   0   0.000 0.200  0.150 0.066 0.200 0.200 0.000
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit Test Data:**

```
#fake data
data(edhec)
ticker1 <- c("ConA","CTA","DisE","EM","EQN","EvD", "FIA", "GM", "LSE","MA", "RV", "SS","FF")
colnames(edhec) <- ticker1 
fund.names <- colnames(edhec)      
port_test <- portfolio.spec(assets=fund.names)
port_test <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_test, type="full_investment")
port_test <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_test, type="long_only")
port_test <- add.constraint(portfolio=port_test, type="box", min=0.0, max=0.2)      
port_test <- add.objective(portfolio=port_test, type="quadratic_utility", risk_aversion=(4.044918))
port_test <- add.objective(portfolio=port_test, type="risk", name="StdDev")
port_test <- add.objective(portfolio=port_test, type="return", name="mean")

bt_port_test <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R=edhec, portfolio= port_test,                                                        optimize_method="ROI", rebalance_on="years", trace=TRUE, training_period= NULL)

chart.Weights(bt_port_test,  ylim=c(0, 1))
extractStats(bt_port_test)
weights_test <- round(extractWeights(bt_port_test),3)
weights_test
head(edhec)

#split data per year (result in list)
ret.year <- split(edhec, f="years")

#calculating yearly VaR
VaRs = rollapply(data = edhec, width = 20, FUN = function(x) VaR(x, p = 0.95, weights= weights_test, portfolio_method="component",method = "historical", by.column = TRUE))
```

I am getting the following error code:

```
 Error in VaR(x, p = 0.95, weights = weights_test, portfolio_method = "component",  : 
  number of items in weights not equal to number of columns in R
```

If tried to create a function:

```
ret.year2 <- ret.year[-c(1,2)]
VAR <- function(p, ret.year2, weights.year){
  a <- for(i in 1:ret.year2)
  b <- for(j in 1:weights.year)
  VaR(a,p=0.95,weights= b, portfolio_method="component",method = "historical")
}
resultat <- VAR(p=0.95,ret.year2=ret.year2, weights.year= weights.year)
```

which unfortunately didn't work out as expected:

```
Error in 1:ret.year2 : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:ret.year2 : numerical expression has 11 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will fit better at a sister site. You can select one or more from [> here <](https://stackexchange.com/sites). A question transfer flag of "Cross Validation" was raised. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: I have edited the questions and it should meet the criterias now.

Comment: It _could_ help if you could show the objects/data which you are feeding to the `VaR` function. Right now it is not very clear.

Comment: Well done on the update. Imported criteria to meet is describing what goes wrong with your code , a.k.a. "error", "error-log", "trace-backs", etc. As that is here not the case and your code does not perform a certain task correct (shows an argument) its becomes a different type of question and belongs at the sister site.

Comment: @brko You can use `dput` or `structure` for weights_rent and R objects to show their content in reproducible manner

Comment: @brko ...cause right now it is still not unequivocal whether these are table, matrices, dataframes or something else...

Comment: Both, R and weights_rent, are xts/zoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the function [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf), it seems like the reason for the error could be the one you´ve mentioned yourself: `weights` argument requires a `vector` of weights - not a `zoo` object or something else. You could try to give `VaR` function what it wants - a vector of numeric values.

And, if you want to get 20 `VaR` function values (one for each year in R) it would seem logical to feed `VaR` one year of data/R at a time, which ultimately would give you the wanted 20 function values.

If you want, you can automate the process and in a loop subset the data by year, 1 year at a time, and feed it to the VaR, then either print the results or store the in some data structure.

**EDIT**: With your fake data you can analyse it like this:

```
library(ROI) 
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog) 
library(ROI.plugin.glpk) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)

# your code here
#split data per year (result in list)
ret.year <- split(edhec, f="years")

# split weights per year
weights.year <- split(weights_test, f="years")

# loop over the list of weights, find corresponding data from edhec and run the analysis
for (i in 1:length(weights.year)){
  weight <- weights.year[[i]]
  year_weight <- as.numeric(format(start(weight), "%Y"))
  weight <- as.vector(weight)

  for (j in 1:length(ret.year)){
    YearlyR <- ret.year[[j]]
    year_R <- as.numeric(format(start(YearlyR), "%Y"))

    if (year_R==year_weight){
      print(paste("BINGO - years match: ", year_R, year_weight, sep=" "))
      result <- VaR(YearlyR, weights= weight, portfolio_method="component",method="historical")
      print(result)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, than it does work, the problem is it only gives me one VaR value for the entire R data set (20 years of daily index data), though my struggle is to get 20 VaR values, instead of one.
My aim is to get for each year in R one VaR value with the defined weights from weights_rent.

Comment: You could feed it one year of `R` at a time which then would give you one `VaR`  function value / year?

Comment: Yeah, that is possible, though, I was looking for a more automated process

Comment: You can automate the process (e.g. subsetting 1 year at a time and feeding it to the `VaR`).

Comment: How could I do that, meaning what would be the quickest way to do it?

Comment: Subset the data by year in a loop.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply/questions. I am fairly certain that this is a quick fix, but I am unable to create the loop. I was able split the the returns table into years (with the split function), but could not really calculate anything with it.

Comment: Well, if you would show the data either with sample/fake data/something so that the issue could be reproduced, it could make the issue solvable. (also the code with loop/split would help)

Comment: I have edited my question and added some fake data and my try to solve it. However, I was not able to create the automatisation with the codes from above.

Comment: With your new code (w fake data) I get an error already at the point where you define `bt_port_test`.   "no applicable method for 'extractObjectiveMeasures' applied to an object of class "c('simpleError', 'error', 'condition')"" . Subsetting the data per year into `ret.year` looks ok though

Comment: This issue can happen if these packages are missing:
install.packages("ROI")
install.packages("ROI.plugin.quadprog")
install.packages("ROI.plugin.glpk")